# Trying to deploy a jRoR app using rubber and getting NoMethodError: undefined method `authorize_port_range' for nil:NilClass

Tags: amazon-ec2, jruby, jrubyonrails, fog

This is my first time using rubber or deploying to Amazon EC2. I am following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2). I've googled all over and nobody else seems to be having this problem. Here's my console log when I run `cap rubber:create_staging`:

```
user529789@user529789-M15x:~/develops/grouper$ cap rubber:create_staging
    triggering load callbacks
  * executing `rubber:init'
  * executing `rubber:create_staging'
Hostname to use for staging instance [production]: 
Roles to use for staging instance [apache,app,collectd,common,db:primary=true,elasticsearch,examples,graphite_server,graphite_web,graylog_elasticsearch,graylog_mongodb,graylog_server,graylog_web,haproxy,mongodb,monit,passenger,postgresql,postgresql_master,web,web_tools]: 
  * executing `rubber:create'
Excon nonblock is not supported by your OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket
Excon nonblock is not supported by your OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket
  * Creating new security group: grouper_production_default
  * Creating new rule: {"source_group_name"=>"grouper_production_default", "source_group_account"=>"<account id redacted>"}
[DEPRECATION] authorize_group_and_owner is deprecated, use authorize_port_range with :group option instead
  * Creating new rule: {"protocol"=>"tcp", "from_port"=>"22", "to_port"=>"22", "source_ips"=>["0.0.0.0/0"]}
NoMethodError: undefined method `authorize_port_range' for nil:NilClass
  add_security_group_rule at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/cloud/fog.rb:182
                     send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2088
           method_missing at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/thread_safe_proxy.rb:13
     sync_security_groups at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/security_groups.rb:221
                     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
     sync_security_groups at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/security_groups.rb:220
                     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
     sync_security_groups at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/security_groups.rb:214
                     each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615
     sync_security_groups at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/security_groups.rb:208
    setup_security_groups at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/security_groups.rb:51
          create_instance at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:255
          create_instance at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:254
         create_instances at /home/user529789/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@grouper/gems/rubber-2.1.0/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/instances.rb:217
                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270
                     call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that its looking for a range and in the stack trace you are giving the range is from one port to the same port and ruby, especially jruby might be construing the port range incorrectly.

you might try running in your version of jruby on irb

`(22..22).to_a` and see what you get. in mri you'd get `[22]` but in jruby there might be an implementation bug.

the code under execution at time of failure I think is here: 
https://github.com/rubber/rubber/blob/v2.1.0/lib/rubber/cloud/fog.rb#L182

EDIT

after looking for a few more minutes, its clear that rubber passes the arguments to the fog gem and I'm pretty sure that even though the range may resolve, the way that fog is using it, expects a range. You might try something like a range from 21 to 23 or 22 to 23 and see if that gets you past the error. Also, as a note, the version of rubber you are using is pretty far behind the master version. I don't have any reference to specify this is desired or not, but you should be aware of it. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround that worked for me is to go to
rubber.yml

and set all of the options related to security group from 'true' to 'false'
Not sure of the effect of this at all but it seems to get through.